# I need a simple example of exporting SQL server query result in Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, export, xlsx

I have been trying to produce Excel files from data of SQL server query for many weeks now. Unfortunately non of the dacade old available data helped me.
I have tried every single solution and library and non of them works.
I just wish to simply read a table from SQL server and simply export it as a .xlsx file.
Could you please write a simple example of how you can do it (not in comments please, in an answer)

Here is one of my many fruitless efforts based on some info on the internet:

```
   //connection is already open
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt ); 

                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
    
                       //Response.  ...  Response gives error! It doesn't work
                       // and.I.dont.know.how.save.as.path.file( .... )     

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using the Office Interoperability library?  Have you tried EPPlus?

Comment: @SteveC Thank you for your comment. No, can you help me how I can use? Can you write it in an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe check out the EPPlus site and follow the examples.  That's the best answer imo